# How do you update cached objects when other APIs also return the cached object as part of the response?

Tags: asp.net-core, caching, redis

I am trying to implement caching using Redis in my ASP.NET MVC application. The way I am planning to do this is by caching what my WebAPI method returns. For example:

GetItems - retrieves from cache if exists; retrieves from DB and adds it in cache if it doesn't

Sample structure of GetItems return object:

```
{
  Id = 1,
  Name = "Books" 
}
```

When I update an item, i will find the item in the cache based on its key and delete it so that next time someone calls the API, it will set the updated data into the cache.

My problem is that I have some other APIs that also returns part of the data of the item. For example, I have an API GetAccounts where this returns the account records but part of the return object is also the name of the items and a few other item related records.

Sample structure of GetAccounts return object:

```
{
  Id = 1,
  Name = "Account 500",
  ItemDetail = {
    Id = 1,
    Name = Books
  }
}
```

So assuming I am on a state where these 2 APIs return are already cached, and then a user edits an item, the cached item in GetItems would be invalidated but the GetAccounts would still contain the same item data. How is this usually solved? Or is the way I'm planning on doing it incorrect?

Comment: are you trying with distributed caching  ?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: I haven't but I think that talks about cache being consistent across multiple servers, but my problem is making sure related cached items are invalidated as needed, or maybe making it known that when a certain item is invalidated, there might be other cached items that needs invalidation as well.